# 20.04: Random DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG after failed to install cpanel

Tags: networking, dns

I'm having issues with my ubuntu DNS settings after failed to install cpanel on my laptop.

At first the internet working fine after the failed install, but after I restart my laptop, I can't browse the internet anymore. 
The browser says: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG.

After that, I try to find the solution, and I find one solution that state to run this command:
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`. 
It worked. But, I had to run that everytime I reboot.

Beside that, now the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG problem appeared randomly, and sometimes it stuck in a loop between DNS_PROBE_STARTED, DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG, and DNS_PROBE_NX_DOMAIN, and after a few minutes, it going back to normal.

Another things that I noticed, when I try to run ping command, it will start very slow, like 30 seconds or something, and after that, it received the response.

Did anyone know what the actual cause of this problem?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:

1. I use ubuntu 20.04 , and I use wireless connection from my android hotspot.
2. The WiFi MTU I believe is 1500

Comment: Wired or WiFi? WiFi MTU? `ip link;ip route`.  Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl ip ip-link ip-route`.

Comment: Which Supported Ubuntu release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi @waltinator, I used WiFi connecting android hotspot, I think the WiFi MTU is on 1500.

Comment: @waltinator And I used ubuntu version 20.04.